# javascript remove multiple values of array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to javascript and I am trying to remove multiple values from an array of objects.

Right now I can remove one object like this

```
if(obj.findObjectByKey(response, 'cat_id', 171) == true) {
    var catId = response.map(item => item.cat_id).indexOf(171);
}
```

In the code above I will remove the item with a id of "171" but now I have an array with multiple values that I would like to remove.

So how can I modify the code above to let me pass in an array of items that I want to remove from the list eg `['171', '172', '173, '174'];`

Answer (score 28):

If you can use ES6, try using JavaScript's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for this.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const remove = [1, 2, 4, 6];

function removeFromArray(original, remove) {
  return original.filter(value => !remove.includes(value));
}

console.log(removeFromArray(nums, remove));
```

This will work just as well with strings.

```js
const nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
const remove = ["1", "2", "4", "6"];

function removeFromArray(original, remove) {
  return original.filter(value => !remove.includes(value));
}

console.log(removeFromArray(nums, remove));
```

This solution also has the added benefit of being immutable. Meaning that you are returning new data rather than morphing the old. Which is considered good practice.

https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over that array, and check for the array element.

```
arrayToRemove = ['171', '172', '173', '174'];

for (i = arrayToRemove.length; i>=0; i--) {
   if(obj.findObjectByKey(response, 'cat_id', arrayToRemove[i]) == true) {
       var catId = response.map(item => item.cat_id).indexOf(arrayToRemove[i]);
       response.splice(catId, 1);
   } 
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is the fastest and most straight forward with least changes to your current code.

*It's important to note that you should loop this from the end of the array to remove to the beginning so you can preserve indices of the other elements in the remaining array.*

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred', age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true },
];
var app = [{ user: 'barney' }, { user: 'fred' }];
_.forEach(app, (v) => {
  users = _.reject(users, { user: v.user });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var userList = [
      { name: 'abhijeet', city: 'pune', id: 1},
      { name: 'rohit', city: 'pune', id: 2},
      { name: 'vicky', city: 'deglur', id: 3},
      { name: 'abhilash', city: 'washim', id: 4},
      { name: 'sumit', city: 'nagpur', id: 5}
    ];

    var removeUsers = [
      { name: 'vicky', city: 'deglur', id: 3},
      { name: 'sumit', city: 'nagpur', id: 5}
    ];

    var idArray = removeUsers.map((user) => user.id);

    userList = userList.filter((item) => {
        return idArray.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
    });
```